# Does DataTables support Persian language?

Tags: jquery, pdf, utf-8, datatables

I am working with Persian data and when printing them as a PDF, just the English data is correct but not the Persian data.
Can anyone help?

Here are the pictures:

[image: before print:]

[image: after Print]

Comment: No, DT uses pdfMake to create PDF's. You must provide your own charset and ship that along with pdfMake if you want persian language -> https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/33 (or similar threads)

Comment: have to problem with fonts, the problem is with character set

Comment: Try following the link  before commenting :) It is a very common issue. The default font in pdfMake does not support a broad range of languages, special chars, right to left and so on. Perhaps, if you provided some example code and what you have tried, someone could answer, but basically the answer is in the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

late answer, but solved.
pdfmake does not support RTL fonts, you have to customize and add your own font to it.
here is an example
[on Github](https://github.com/hekmatnajafi/datatable-exportPDF-to-persian)

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are **inaccurate**, and not to the point and do not answer the question. As you know, the ludicrous PdfMake plugin uses the Roboto font by default. This font does not support Persian characters/script. To solve this problem, you should change the default font to your desired Farsi font. The very first action you need to take is to open 'vfs_fonts.js' file. This file has the following structure:

```js
this.pdfMake = this.pdfMake || {}; this.pdfMake.vfs = {
  "arial.ttf": "AAEAA...MYXRu",
  "another_one.ttf": "XXXX...XXXX"
};
```

Each of the "AAEAA...MYXRu strings, as explained by @AndrewJames is the base64-encoded representation of the related font file. You need to change these, by the specific strings for your font.
To generate the string, you should go to [dataurlmaker](https://dataurl.sveinbjorn.org/#dataurlmaker). Just then, paste the (very long) string generated by dataurlmaker into your vfs_fonts.js file. 
Make sure NOT to include any preamble provided by dataurlmaker ("data:application/octet-stream;base64,"). Include only the base64 string itself.

After using the dataurl as recommended, and then changing the font name in pdfmake.js and using that name in vfs_fonts.js, the font gets changed. however, there still remain the main problem and that is the problem with RTL. Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer datatable docs https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/.

I have not tested this but i think this should wok.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
            "language": {
                "url": "dataTables.german.lang"
            }
        } );
```

Comment: this is not what i mean, this will change the language of buttons. i asked for content. when i load the data from database, it comes with two language (English and Persian). when im making a pdf file of it, the Persian data replaced with symbols but the English data is correct. so how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

First you should download the plugin:  [plugin for Persian lang](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/i18n/Persian.lang)

Then upload this file to the directory where you are working and make an ajax request:

Without cross domain Ajax request:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "language": {
            "url": "Persian.lang"
        }
    } );
} );
</script>
```

With cross domain Ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Persian.json"
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: No need for downloading, DT have a CDN, `url: 'http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Persian.json'`

Comment: Yes, thanks @davidkonrad. I had advised to download the file because cross domain Ajax request is not allowed, but with JSONP It's possible. now I edit the answer.

Comment: I think you must reevaluate that assumption -> http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/2007/ if the server support cross domain there is no problem, and a CDN will need to do that. Besides that, OP ask for correct persian in the generated PDF's, not the persian translation plugin :)

Comment: this is not what i mean, this will change the language of buttons. i asked for content. when i load the data from database, it comes with two language (English and Persian). when im making a pdf file of it, the Persian data replaced with symbols but the English data is correct. so how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried to see if your printing software supports this language? Maybe you should change the character set.